# Update ProgressBar outside of recycler view adapter android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, progress-bar, android-view

I want update progress bar in parent activity where recycler view is located.when user clicked on each radio buttons add a number to progress bar I have done it but I don't know how can I pass data from recycler view adapter to parent activity.

enter image description here

```html
class MbtiQuestionAdapter(val questionList: QuestionList) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionViewHolder>() {
    var maps = arrayListOf<HashMap<String, String>>()
    var i = 0
    var e = 0
    var n = 0
    var t = 0
    var j = 0
    var p = 0
    var f = 0
    var s = 0
    var typeQuestion = ""
    var testnumbers = 0


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): QuestionViewHolder {

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(
            AminAmix.com.socialpersonality.R.layout.question_row,
            parent,
            false
        )
        return QuestionViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }


    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: QuestionViewHolder, position: Int) {

        //val question = questions.get(position)
        if (questionList.questions[position].tip != "") {
            holder.view.txtTitletipsQuestionRow.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            //      holder.view.imgtips.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.view.txtTipsQuestion.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.view.txtTipsQuestion.text = questionList.questions[position].tip

        } else {
            holder.view.imageView15.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            holder.view.shapeBlue.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.view.shapeGreen.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.view.shapeCircle.visibility = View.VISIBLE


        }

        holder.view.txtAmountQuestion.text = questionList.questions.size.toString()
        holder.view.txtCurrentQuestion.text = (position + 1).toString()
        val question = questionList.questions.get(position).title
        Log.i("Position", position.toString())
        val answers = questionList.questions.get(position).answers

        var valueOfRadio = ""

        if (questionList.questions.get(position).type == "range") {
            holder.view.cardAB.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            for (answer in answers) {
                val value = answer.value
                typeQuestion = answer.title

                Log.i("Position2", value.toString())
                if (answer.title == "Agree") {
                    holder.view.txtQuestionDisAgree.text = answer.title

                } else {
                    holder.view.txtQuestionAgree.text = answer.title

                }


            }
            holder.view.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->

                if (checkedId == AminAmix.com.socialpersonality.R.id.radioButton_middle) {
                    Log.i("Radio", "0")
                    valueOfRadio = "0"



                }
                if (checkedId == AminAmix.com.socialpersonality.R.id.radioButton_agree1) {
                    Log.i("Radio", "1")
                    valueOfRadio = "1"

                }
                if (checkedId == AminAmix.com.socialpersonality.R.id.radioButton_agree2) {
                    Log.i("Radio", "2")
                    valueOfRadio = "2"

                }
                if (checkedId == AminAmix.com.socialpersonality.R.id.radioButton_disagree1) {
                    Log.i("Radio", "-1")
                    valueOfRadio = "-1"

                }
                if (checkedId == AminAmix.com.socialpersonality.R.id.radioButton_disagree_2) {
                    Log.i("Radio", "-2")
                    valueOfRadio = "-2"

                }

                val checked = group.findViewById(checkedId) as RadioButton
                val list: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
                list.add(checked.getText().toString())

                Log.i("Chekkk", list.toString())
                Log.i(
                    "checkedId", position.toString()
                )

                var idIf = ""
                var typeIf = ""
                var testValue = 0


                var map = HashMap<String, String>();


                var radioInt = valueOfRadio.toInt()
                var selectedAnswers = questionList.questions[position].answers


                if (radioInt > 0) {
                    for (answer in selectedAnswers) {
                        if (answer.title == "Agree") {
                            typeIf = answer.type
                            testValue = answer.value
                            holder.view.txtQuestionDisAgree.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#5E5E5E"));
                            holder.view.txtQuestionAgree.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B2B2B2"));
                            holder.view.txtCurrentQuestion.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                            holder.view.txtAmountQuestion.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                            holder.view.txtCurrentQuestion2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                            holder.view.txtTitleQuestions.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                            holder.view.questionsTik.visibility = View.VISIBLE


                        }
                    }

                } else if (radioInt < 0) {
                    for (answer in selectedAnswers) {
                        if (answer.title == "Disagree") {
                            typeIf = answer.type
                            testValue = answer.value
                            holder.view.txtQuestionAgree.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#5E5E5E"));
                            holder.view.txtQuestionDisAgree.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B2B2B2"));
                            holder.view.txtCurrentQuestion.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                            holder.view.txtAmountQuestion.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                            holder.view.txtCurrentQuestion2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                            holder.view.txtTitleQuestions.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                            holder.view.questionsTik.visibility = View.VISIBLE


                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    holder.view.txtQuestionAgree.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B2B2B2"));
                    holder.view.txtQuestionDisAgree.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B2B2B2"));
                    holder.view.txtCurrentQuestion.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                    holder.view.txtAmountQuestion.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                    holder.view.txtCurrentQuestion2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                    holder.view.txtTitleQuestions.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                    holder.view.questionsTik.visibility = View.VISIBLE


                }

                var absolutResultRadio = Math.abs(valueOfRadio.toInt())


                //  map["Q" + "_" + idIf.toString() + "_" + typeIf.toString()] = valueOfRadio
                map["Q" + (position + 1).toString()] =
                    typeIf.toString() + "_" + absolutResultRadio * testValue

                var con = maps.any { it.containsKey("Q" + (position + 1).toString()) }
                if (maps.any { con == true }) {// filter
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        maps.removeIf { it.containsKey("Q" + (position + 1)) }
                        testnumbers = testnumbers - 1

                    }
                    testnumbers = testnumbers + 1

                    maps.add(map)
                    Log.i("maps", "in dare ejra mishe")


                } else {
                    maps.add(map)
                    testnumbers = testnumbers + 1

                }

            }
            Log.i ( "testnumber2" , testnumbers.toString())


        } else {
            holder.view.cardRange.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            holder.view.radioButtonFirstAAndB.text = answers[0].title
            holder.view.radioButtonSecondAAndB.text = answers[1].title

            holder.view.radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->


                if (checkedId == AminAmix.com.socialpersonality.R.id.radioButtonFirstAAndB) {
                    Log.i("Radio", "1")
                    valueOfRadio = "1"

                }

                if (checkedId == AminAmix.com.socialpersonality.R.id.radioButtonSecondAAndB) {
                    Log.i("Radio", "-1")
                    valueOfRadio = "-1"

                }


                val checked = group.findViewById(checkedId) as RadioButton
                val list: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
                list.add(checked.getText().toString())

                Log.i("Chekkk", list.toString())
                Log.i(
                    "checkedId", position.toString()
                )

                var idIf = ""
                var typeIf = ""
                var testValue = 0


                var map = HashMap<String, String>();


                var radioInt = valueOfRadio.toInt()
                var selectedAnswers = questionList.questions[position].answers


                if (radioInt > 0) {


                    typeIf = selectedAnswers[0].type
                    testValue = selectedAnswers[0].value

                    holder.view.txtCurrentQuestion.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                    holder.view.txtAmountQuestion.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                    holder.view.txtCurrentQuestion2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                    holder.view.txtTitleQuestions.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                    holder.view.questionsTik.visibility = View.VISIBLE


                } else if (radioInt < 0) {

                    typeIf = selectedAnswers[1].type
                    testValue = selectedAnswers[1].value
                    holder.view.txtCurrentQuestion.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                    holder.view.txtAmountQuestion.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                    holder.view.txtCurrentQuestion2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                    holder.view.txtTitleQuestions.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B6095"));
                    holder.view.questionsTik.visibility = View.VISIBLE


                }

                var absolutResultRadio = Math.abs(valueOfRadio.toInt())


                //  map["Q" + "_" + idIf.toString() + "_" + typeIf.toString()] = valueOfRadio
                map["Q" + (position + 1).toString()] =
                    typeIf.toString() + "_" + absolutResultRadio * testValue

                var con = maps.any { it.containsKey("Q" + (position + 1).toString()) }
                if (maps.any { con == true }) {// filter
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        maps.removeIf { it.containsKey("Q" + (position + 1)) }


                    }


                    maps.add(map)
                    Log.i("maps", "in dare ejra mishe")


                } else {
                    maps.add(map)
                }

            }


        }




        Log.i("mapSize", maps.toString())
        Log.i("mapSize", maps.size.toString())
        if (maps.size.toInt() == questionList.questions.size
        ) {

            Log.i("maps", "Halaaaaaaaaaaa in dare ejra mishe")
            Log.i("Mapss", "SomeText: " + Gson().toJson(maps))
            val dataOfTestToJson = Gson().toJson(maps).toString()
            val eRegex = Regex("E_(\\d+)")
            val iRegex = Regex("I_(\\d+)")
            val sRegex = Regex("S_(\\d+)")
            val nRegex = Regex("N_(\\d+)")
            val fRegex = Regex("F_(\\d+)")
            val tRegex = Regex("T_(\\d+)")
            val pRegex = Regex("P_(\\d+)")
            val jRegex = Regex("J_(\\d+)")
            e = eRegex.findAll(dataOfTestToJson).map { it.groupValues[1].toInt() }.sum()
            i = iRegex.findAll(dataOfTestToJson).map { it.groupValues[1].toInt() }.sum()
            s = sRegex.findAll(dataOfTestToJson).map { it.groupValues[1].toInt() }.sum()
            n = nRegex.findAll(dataOfTestToJson).map { it.groupValues[1].toInt() }.sum()
            f = fRegex.findAll(dataOfTestToJson).map { it.groupValues[1].toInt() }.sum()
            t = tRegex.findAll(dataOfTestToJson).map { it.groupValues[1].toInt() }.sum()
            p = pRegex.findAll(dataOfTestToJson).map { it.groupValues[1].toInt() }.sum()
            j = jRegex.findAll(dataOfTestToJson).map { it.groupValues[1].toInt() }.sum()

            val data = JSONObject()
            data.put("E", e)
            data.put("I", i)
            data.put("S", s)
            data.put("N", n)
            data.put("T", t)
            data.put("F", f)
            data.put("J", j)
            data.put("P", p)
            Log.i(
                "dataSexy",
                data.toString()
            )


            Log.i(
                "mapsSexy",
                "I = $i" + " " + "E = $e" + " " + "S= $s" + " " + "N = $n" + " " + "F = $f" + " " + "T = $t" + " " + "P = $p" + " " + "J = $j"
            )

            val context = holder.view.context
            val intent = Intent(context, LoadingMbtiActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("e", e.toString())
            intent.putExtra("i", i.toString())
            intent.putExtra("s", s.toString())
            intent.putExtra("n", n.toString())
            intent.putExtra("f", f.toString())
            intent.putExtra("t", t.toString())
            intent.putExtra("p", p.toString())
            intent.putExtra("j", j.toString())
            intent.putExtra("data", data.toString())
            context.startActivity(intent)
            (context as Activity).finish()
        }

        holder.view.txtQuestionInRow.text = question

    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return questionList.questions.size

    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }


}


class QuestionViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {


}
```

tps://i.stack.imgur.com/aQiS4.png

```html
class MBTITEST : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var token: String


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mbtitest)
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black)



        val preferences: SharedPreferences =
            applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("SOCIAL_PERSONALITY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        token = preferences.getString("TOKEN", null).toString() //second parameter default value.
        var tokenBAr = "Bearer $token"
        getQuestions(tokenBAr)

    }

    fun getQuestions(token: String) {
        val apilnterface: APIInterface = APIClient().getClient()!!.create(APIInterface::class.java)

        var call: Call<QuestionList> = apilnterface.getQuestions(token)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<QuestionList> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<QuestionList>,
                response: Response<QuestionList>
            ) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
//                    Toast.makeText(
//                        this@MBTITEST,
//                        "Testatol GolMohammadi",
//                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
//                    )
//                        .show()
//                    Log.w("RESGetID", "${response.body().toString()}")
                    val dataFromResponse = response.body()
                    val questionList = dataFromResponse?.questions
                    val size = questionList?.size
                    val title = questionList?.get(0)?.title

                    print(questionList)
                    Log.w("QuestionListDaDa", questionList.toString())
                    Log.w("QuestionListDaDa", size.toString())
                    Log.w("QuestionListDaDa", title.toString())

                    runOnUiThread {
                        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
                            this@MBTITEST,
                            LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                            false
                        )
                        recycler_questions.layoutManager = layoutManager
                        recycler_questions.setHasFixedSize(true)
                        recycler_questions.adapter?.setHasStableIds(true)
                        Collections.shuffle(dataFromResponse?.questions)
                        recycler_questions.adapter =
                            dataFromResponse?.let { MbtiQuestionAdapter(it) }
                        txtCountTotal.text = questionList?.size.toString()
                        var mbtiAdapter =   dataFromResponse?.let { MbtiQuestionAdapter(it) }
                       var testnumbers = mbtiAdapter?.testnumbers
                        textView15.setText(testnumbers.toString())
                        Log.i("testnumber", testnumbers.toString())




//                        btnShowRes.setOnClickListener {
//                         //   dataFromResponse?.let { MbtiQuestionAdapter(it) }?.activateButtons(true)
//                            val intent = Intent(this@MBTITEST, ShowTestResultActivity::class.java)
//                            startActivity(intent)
//                            finish()
//                        }


                    }
                }
                if (response.code() == 400) {
                    try {
                        val jObjError = JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            jObjError.getString("message"),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }

                }
                if (response.code() == 401) {
                    try {
                        val preferences: SharedPreferences =
                            applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
                                "SOCIAL_PERSONALITY",
                                Context.MODE_PRIVATE
                            )
                        preferences.edit().putString("TOKEN", "").apply()
                        val jObjError = JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            jObjError.getString("message"),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()


                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        val intent = Intent(this@MBTITEST, FirstPageActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()

                    }

                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<QuestionList>, t: Throwable) {

                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MBTITEST,
                    " Register is not ok",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                )
                    .show()
            }

        })
    }


}
```

Comment: You can signal events from adapter to activity using an interface or a lambda callback passed as a constructor parameter. Add your current adapter and MainActivity code in the question.

Comment: thank you arpit . I want pass testNumber from adapter to MbtiActivity

Comment: And when do you want to pass it? Like whenever its value changes or after some click event or something else?

Comment: Also,  you have pasted your entire class here. Can you edit your question to keep only the relevant pieces?

Comment: @ArpitShukla I want whenever value change in adapter  automatically add a number to progress bar.
And I am new hear what kind of change in question do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like what @Arpit Shukla mentioned you can pass data between adapter and activity using lambdas or functions

add a function as a parameter to your adapter's constructor

```
class MbtiQuestionAdapter(val questionList: QuestionList,val onRadioButtonClick : (Int) -> Unit)
```

in your activity define a function to update your progress bar and it takes a number as a parameter or whatever you want

```
private fun updateProgressBar(testNumber : Int){
//update progress bar
}
```

pass the above function to adapter constructor when you initialize it

```
recycler_questions.adapter = dataFromResponse?.let { MbtiQuestionAdapter(it){number -> updateProgressBar(number)} }
```

lastly call the onRadioButtonClick in your adapter when you want to pass the number to your activity

```
onRadioButtonClick(number)
```

Comment: I have another question if I want when user click on all radio buttons in adapter shows a button and when user touch it intent to result activity. what is your solution?

Comment: @Zibfit i don't understand what you really want to do, can you be more detailed

Comment: As indicated in the code, I have a number of items here. The user determines by clicking on each radio buttons that an item has been left behind. Now I want a button to appear under the all items when all the items are clicked.

Comment: You can add another function in ativity that shows the button you want and call it in adapter when all items are clicked